# value is not being caught by regex

Tags: javascript, regex

here is my regex

```
/(^-?\d\d*\.\d{0,2}$)|(^-?\d\d*\$)|(^-?\.\d\d{0,2}$)/
```

It catches everything I need to catch, except the following

```
.111
```

It catches .1111.
I want to allow up to 2 optional digits after decimal point.

Thank you.

Comment: the middle one. i don't think you mean to escape the `$`.

Comment: Why do you want to "catch" (i.e., match) `0.111` if you want to allow only up to 2 digits after the decimal point. It is not supposed to match, is it? It has 3 digits after the decimal point.

Comment: BTW, `\d\d{0,2}` can be simplified to `\d{1,3}`.

Comment: @DaniëlKnippers I think he means 1 required digit, 2 optional digits after it.

Comment: @Barmar Perhaps, but that would violate the 2nd of his 3 OR expressions since that one does not contain a decimal point at all and simply matches `-?\d+` (he writes it as `-?\d\d*`). But I suppose it makes sense; IF there is a decimal point there should be at least 1 digit after it. So as you said `\d{1,3}` should do it (which is what he already has, albeit less simple like you noted too).

Comment: It's not matching `.1111` here: http://regex101.com/r/nQ1rJ1/1

Answer (score 1):

Does this do what you want?

```
^-?\d*(?:\.\d{1,2})?$
```

[Demo.](http://regex101.com/r/oQ1lX5/1)